# VBscript using variable from text file error

Tags: vbscript, readline, filesystemobject

Good day all.

What I am trying to do is ready a value from a text file and using it as a variable within the code. The text file holds a path directory, that i want to use to create another folder in with a datestamp.

This is what it looks like:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading = 1

Set objTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\MyFolder\Settings.txt", ForReading)


For i = 0 to 0

    objTextFile.ReadLine

Next


New_Path = objTextFile.ReadLine
FSO.CreateFolder New_Path & Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2)

objTextFile.Close
```

I get an error that says `Bad file name or number`
But when I use `Wscript.Echo New_Path` it shows me exactly the right path that I need. Why is it not using it if it comes back correctly?

The first line has comments so I read the second line that contains the path that looks like this: "C:\NewFolder\"

Comment: "C:\NewFolder\" exactly the same as in the test file. That's why I'm so confused on why I get that error

Answer (score 0):

In the text file i took away the "" between the Directory and it worked